# Custom Module in Open Cart not showing in admin section

Tags: php, opencart

I am a newbee to opencart and php.

I am trying to create a custome category module to display categories on home page.

I copied the respective files in MVCL folders ,changes the name of classes with the file's name .

But the module is not not showing in the list of  modules in admin section.

I dont know where i am making a  wrong move.

Is there any way to create a module in opencart?

thanks

Comment: This is correct thing to do. Did you edit the language file to reflect new module name? Any errors?

Comment: no error since i can't see module in admin listing , yes updated the language file for the module...

Comment: where should i check for errors, there is not much in language file..

Comment: You did not forget to copy and rename files in admin by any chance? The are two sets of files, one in catalog and one in admin...

Comment: ohh thanx ,it worked , another thing i need to display category at home page, should i modify the existing tpl for category in module or can i add this without adding any seprate module..

Comment: also the working module and the existing category has the same setting , i can't get both working together..

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. If you need a separate module, copy and edit catalog files including tpl. You need to change setting name so your module will have it's own setting.

Comment: I need a seprate  module , how do i change setting name?

Comment: Just like you changed class and file names, go through controllers and change setting to something else. Also tpl form field names.

Comment: I posted an answer. Hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 1):

You did not forget to copy and rename files in admin by any chance? The are two sets of files, one in catalog and one in admin.

Aside from changing names of files and classes, you need to change setting and config names. Basically, find and change **all references** to `category` with your own, e.g. `my_category`.

```
$this->model_setting_setting->editSetting('category', $this->request->post);
...
if (isset($this->request->post['category_module'])) {
        $this->data['modules'] = $this->request->post['category_module'];
    } elseif ($this->config->get('category_module')) { 
        $this->data['modules'] = $this->config->get('category_module');
    }
```

etc.
Also in tpl, change form field names, example:

```
<select name="category_module[<?php echo $module_row; ?>][layout_id]">
```

change to:

```
<select name="my_category_module[<?php echo $module_row; ?>][layout_id]">
```

This goes for both, admin and catalog files.